# Illegal Russian Forums

Tags: tls, certificates

I recently found this link `hxxps://maza.cc:888` and it was saying *No required SSL certificate was sent*. How can I bypass to see the content on this site?

Comment: May be its not expecting direct traffic via web browser.

Comment: Sounds like it's expecting an SSL client certificate

Answer (score 8):

If they do a proper client certificate check you cannot bypass the restriction, same as you cannot bypass properly implemented password prompt. Apart from that breaking the security of a specific system is explicitly excluded on this site.

Comment: how can I add dummy certificate?

Comment: @user3501673: I don't think your comment demonstrates enough of "an understanding of the concepts involved" so the rule "break the security of a specific system for you are off-topic" still applies.